# getting placeholder text with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm using the latest from rails and [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) but I can't get my inputs to show placeholder text. When I add the following:

```
@placeholderText: @grayLight
```

To my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less I get a Less::Error
Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

```
Syntax Error on line 30
  (in /home/ubuntu/new-project/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
```

Update **
The error is gone now thanks to xnm but I still don't have placeholder text.
Here is my

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
body { padding-top: 60px; }

@import "twitter/bootstrap/responsive";

// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png');
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png');

// Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
@fontAwesomeEotPath: asset-path('fontawesome-webfont.eot');
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: asset-path('fontawesome-webfont.woff');
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: asset-path('fontawesome-webfont.ttf');
@fontAwesomeSvgzPath: asset-path('fontawesome-webfont.svgz');
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: asset-path('fontawesome-webfont.svg');

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome";

// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
@linkColor: #ff0000;
@placeholderText: @grayLight;
```

and here is my html:

```
<div class="placeholding-input">
  <input type="text" class="text-input" autocomplete="off" name="user[name]" maxlength="20">
  <span class="placeholder">Full name</span>
</div>
```

The generated stylesheet just doesn't give me the placeholder styles. I think I'm supposed to @import something but I can't find any information.

Comment: The full error would help. And is `bootstrap_and_overrides.less.css` a typo? because if not, that's your problem right there.

Comment: Yes you're right. Typo fixed and error added but I don't think it will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. Apparently the correct way is:

```
<input type="text" class="text-input" name="user[name]" maxlength="20" placeholder="Full name">
```

Very confusing since I copied the incorrect way from the twitter homepage.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike sass, less uses semicolons at the end of each line.

```
@placeholderText: @grayLight;
```

Comment: Thanks, that made the error go away but I'm still not getting placehodler text. Please see update above.

Answer (score 0):

see this issue with updates on this.
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/239